# How to use opendir with credentials

Tags: php, opendir

I want to be able to connect to a distant folder based on user's input.
The system has to be compatible with different sharing protocols so I can't just use FTP in every case (distant folders are not necessarily implementing FTP).

Right now `opendir('//HDD/Music');` works because this is a public folder, but for others that need username/password it doesn't work. I already tried `opendir('//username:password@HDD/Music');` which doesn't work.

I don't want to mount the folder either (net use) because this code is intended to be used by normal users and shouldn't interfere with their environment.

To sum up:

`opendir('//HDD/Public_folder');` works
`opendir('//username:password@HDD/Public_folder');` doesn't work

`opendir('ftp://HDD/disk1/Public_folder');` works
`opendir('ftp://username:password@HDD/disk1/Private_folder');` works

Thanks.

Comment: `allow_url_fopen` is disabled. If you enable error reporting, you'll probably see that that message. Furthermore, you should just use a an ftp connection instead, as that's generally the most widely accepted amongst shared hosting environments.

Comment: I checked and allow_url_fopen is enabled in my conf. Also, the system has to be compatible with several protocol, for example a user who has a shared smb folder on his network has to use smb.